# How can this contract buy and sell a token multiple times in one transaction?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, etherscan

I have discovered a contract that can buy and sell multiple times within the same transaction. How does that contract work, and where can I find this contract? Thank you.
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x4bf9644ebf9f5f44193420005e73f8f04bda15e357619233f018d344f137d103
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it is an arbitrage transaction – changing tokens several times with different paths to get some profit from unbalanced pools.
For more information you can google for "mev", "flashbots" and so on, there is a plenty of info including sources of such contracts.

Also you can check https://eigenphi.io/ service for more such transactions (you need to check "arbitrage", not "sandwich")

As for coding contracts with several transfers - it is simple. You just do several calls to several contracts with different calldata